# How to use index match with IF in excel?

Tags: excel

Table1

```
   A         B            C            D   
1 Seq        Item     Re-Order Qty  On-hand Qty
2  1          X         10           15
3  2          Y         10           5
4  3          Z         10           10
```

Other worksheet:
Table2

Expected output:

```
    A           B            C
1   Seq       Item      Re-Order Qty
2   1          N/A          N/A
3   2           Y           10
4   3          N/A          N/A
```

In table2 I need to put in column 2 equation like this:

```
Index(Table1[Item],Match(table2[Seq],tabel1[Seq],0) WHERE table1[reorder qty] > table1[On-hand Qty]
```

I'm not sure how such requirement could be managed?

Comment: Can you please fill in `Table2` with the expected output of this function?  Also, does your `Table1` have multiple entries for `Seq`?  If so, can you add a duplicate to your input and show what the output should be in that case?  It appears you just want to filter `Table1` based on the condition that `reorder < on-hand`.  I'm not clear on the purpose of `Table2`.

Comment: @Byron: I added expected results in 'table2'.
Actually you are right I need to filter 'table1' where onhand is less than re order (I corrected this as the great than sign was not correct).
I know I can simply filter but I need it in a separate sheet so could this be managed through vlookup or index match? I mean in general, to select data from array if certain formula is achieved as true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done.  It requires the use of an array formula in `Table2`.

Normally with an `INDEX` you simply use a range of cells as the `array` (first argument of the formula).  In this case, we will give it a new `array` to return based on the results of a conditional (your `WHERE` clause).

I will start with the picture of results and then give the formulas.  For me, `Table1` is on the left, `Table2` on the right.

[image: picture of tables]

**Formulas**

The formulas are very similar, the main difference is which column to return in the `IF` part which generates the `array` for `INDEX`.  The conditional part of the `IF` is the same for all columns.  Note that using Tables here really helps copying around the formulas since the ranges cannot change under us.

These are all array formulas and need to be entered with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

`Table2[Item]`

```
=INDEX(IF(Table1[Re-Order Qty]>Table1[On-hand Qty],Table1[Item],"N/A"), MATCH([@Seq],Table1[Seq],0))
```

`Table2[Re-Order Qty]`

```
=INDEX(IF(Table1[Re-Order Qty]>Table1[On-hand Qty],Table1[Re-Order Qty],"N/A"), MATCH([@Seq],Table1[Seq],0))
```

`Table2[On-hand Qty]`

```
=INDEX(IF(Table1[Re-Order Qty]>Table1[On-hand Qty],Table1[On-hand Qty],"N/A"), MATCH([@Seq],Table1[Seq],0))
```

The main idea behind these formulas is:

- Return a new array based on the conditional.  This new array will return the desired column (`Item`, `Re-order`, ...) or it will return `N/A` if the conditional is `FALSE`.  This requires the array formula entry since it is going row by row in the `IF`.
- The `MATCH` part of the formula to get the row number is "standard".  We are simply looking for the `Seq` number in `Table1`.  This determines which row of the new `array` to return.